# How do I have a client template that changes between edit and read mode in a Telerik MVC grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I am creating a Telerik MVC UI grid and one of my properties in the record view model is a numeric company id.

What I want my grid to display is the display name for the company in the column when reading the grid, but when creating a new record (or editing an existing record) I would like it to show a drop down with possible values the user can select.

I've done the first part with `c.Bound(x => x.CompanyId).ClientTemplate('#= getcompanyName(CompanyId)#');` and that works fine, but I don't see anything in the examples or API reference on how to have an editing template different than the display template.

I'm sure I am just missing something, since one example on Telerik's own website shows it (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom) but the source code they show is clearly missing the definition for the drop down box (easily seen in that their example passes up a `categories` ViewData element but none of the provided source code actually uses that.

Any hints on what I"m missing to accomplish this?

**Edit:**

Ok, so after bashing my head against a wall I *think* what I want is to create a shared editor template, then do `column.Bound(x => x.CompanyId).EditorTemplateName("IdNamePairDropdown").EditorViewData(new { IdNamePairs = Model.AvailableCompanies });`.

Of course this doesn't work, and gives me an `ArgumentNullReference` exception even though at the break `ViewData["IdNamePairs"]` gives me the correct non-null collection, but at least it's a hint.

**Edit 2:**

Looks like the solution is to do the following in your grid definition:

```
              c.Bound(x => x.MarketingCompanyId).Title("Marketer")
                  .ClientTemplate("#= getCompanyName(MarketingCompanyId) #")
                  .EditorTemplateName("IdNamePairDropdown")
                  .EditorViewData(new { IdNamePairs = Model.AvailableCompanies, IdNamePairName = "marketing_companies" });
```

Then create the corrosponding Editor Template in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/IdNamePairDropdown.cshtml`

@using System.Collections

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("id_pair_dropdown_" + ViewData["IdNamePairName"])
      .DataValueField("Id") 
      .DataTextField("Name")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true"})
      .BindTo((IEnumerable) ViewData["IdNamePairs"])))
```

This correctly allows a distinct drop down per column when in edit mode.

the only missing part is how to save the output, as selecting a value in the drop down and clicking the Update button returns the default value of the column.

Comment: Quick question...do you what a grid that behaves exactly like the one in on  the Telerik demo site? I work with the kendo ui almost every day and it can be frustrating as their api is very poorly documented, their stuff usually performs as expected but wow they need to work on documenting the api.

Comment: Pretty much the same functionality except i'm doing inline editing instead of cell/batch editing.  Glad I'm not the only one lost in their documentation :)

Comment: OK...I just got back from lunch. I have to knock out a few things for my boss but I will post a working grid for you early this evening.

Comment: Not a problem, extremely appreciated as I keep perusing the docs and have still come up empty handed.

Comment: Fyi, I just updated it with the path I have so far figured out since I posted the question.  As a note I realized I did have one difference from the example, in which case I have 4 columns which are going to have drop downs but each with different id/name pairs.  It appears that I an make a separate editor template for each and stuff the data in specific `ViewData` entries but that seems crazy wasteful.

Comment: Well it looks like you made it past the editor template mystery lol. I tried building dynamic drop downs that reuse the same editor template but the performance was better with a separate editor for each one...your going the right direction. You have the grid figured out, I Think the only thing your missing is an onChange event for your drop down. Your drop down list has events..you hook them the same way as the grid. evt => { evt.Change("myList_OnChange")} from there grab a client side reference to the drop down and you can do what ever you want with it. You got this...

Comment: Going to put this on the backburner.  Hooking into the event is all fine and good but I'm having trouble setting the data correctly in the grid itself (things seem funky, like `grid.Select()` throwing an exception).  Telerik support suggested I use one template per field and that they *have* to be named the same as the grid property.  After spending 5 hours on this I just need to move on, as there is probably more complexity in my use case down the line and deadlines are looming :-/.  Custom popup editing it is....

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but since it doesn't have an answer, I thought I would give it one.  All one needs to do is define the column as a ForiegnKey column and provide an Editor Template for it.  Here is a column definition that works in one of my grids:

```
col.ForeignKey(c => c.TypeId_kendoGrid, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ProductTypes, "Value", "Text").Title("Type").Width(150);
```

Then the Editor Template (which I think is included in the Kendo package) is in a file called GridForeignKey.cshtml:

```
@model object

@(
 Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)        
                   .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
  )
```

You may notice that my property name looks a little funky (TypeId_kendoGrid).  That's because in my case the field is nullable and the grid had a difficult time binding null to it.  So in my ViewModel class I do this:

```
public string TypeId_kendoGrid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.TypeId.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            int i;
            this.TypeId = int.TryParse(value, out i) ? (int?)i : null;
        }
    }
```

Where my Model property is TypeId.